# How to calculate time ? in postgresql example 08:00:00 - 07:30:00 = 0.3hour?

Tags: postgresql, time, timestamp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpaYh.png)

```
SELECT time_in,time_out
FROM appointment_trainer;
```

i want to calculate it exmaple 08:00:00 - 07:30:00 = 0.3hour ? is it possible ins postgresql ?

Comment: The difference between 8:00 and 7:30 is NOT 0.3h but 0.5. Do you want 0h 30min or 0.5h?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a20b185c646d2a04941953aa28ccee0c)

If you want to get a time like `00:30:00` then you can do:

```
SELECT time_out - time_in
FROM appointment_trainer
```

This returns a type `interval`. If you want to get a type `time`, you can cast it afterwards:

```
SELECT (time_out - time_in)::time
FROM appointment_trainer
```

If you want to get `0.5` hours, you can use `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)` which returns number of seconds of the `interval`, which can be calculated into hours, of course:

```
SELECT extract(epoch from time_out - time_in) / 60 / 60
FROM appointment_trainer
```

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for ACCEPTING, I'd appreciate if you could UPVOTE as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Subtract them:

```
select time_out - time_in
FROM appointment_trainer;
```

That will return an [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) which is the data type in SQL to represent a "duration"

Comment: My issues have been resolved thank you sir